# When AndroidClientHandler needs to be called from BackgroundThread on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using XF pcl.

I recently realized I can change HttpClient implementation to AndroidClientHandler which is better.

But since I changed it, the exception is thrown because HttpClient's async method needs to be called from backgroundThread. (as I know, it's done automatically on iOS)

But my question is that "when the exception is thrown"?

I changed some code where the exception has been thrown with using Task.run(async ...) to make it be invoked on the Background thread.

NOW, I'm WONDERING if I should have changed all the codes that using HttpClient method because it could be a problem in a future.

OR it's done.

Thanks.

Comment: AndroidClientHandler does not require HttpClient's async method to be called on backgroundThread, unless you are calling `.Wait()`, can you post example of your code?

Comment: @AkashKava Hi Akash, I think actually it does. Since I changed HttpClient implementation option for android project, the exception message says "network should be called on background thread". My code is normal. client = new HttpClient(); and result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

Comment: Try to check source code for AndroidClientHandler and you will see references to `Task.Run`, https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs

Comment: I just saw it. It's very weird. and please look this. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44961

Comment: This is exactly what I faced. and it says "fixed". What's going on?

Comment: I'm using XF 2.3.3.180, which is recentest stable version.

Comment: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/416 This is exactly what I'm facing.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87970/xamarin-forms-2-3-4-192-pre2#latest  I wrote it here too.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/247
According to this, It turns out that this is fixed on Xamarin.android 7.1.
Is this right?
Then it wouldn't be included in stable release since Xamarin.Android version is 7.0.2.42 now.
Am I correct? 
So I better wait, then fine?

Comment: Yes, I guess AndroidClientHandler was brand new so there may be some bugs slipped.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/247

According to this, It turns out that this is fixed on Xamarin.android 7.1.

Then it's not included in stable release since Xamarin.Android version is 7.0.2.42 now.

So I better wait the next update a little bit longer.